# Shortcut for a multiline J/K

Tags: vimrc

This question is a sort of follow-up to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466202/how-to-go-back-in-vim-to-last-cursor-position, which asks how to be able to do something like `17j` and then `17k` to jump back to the current position.

One answer suggested using something like `m'17j` to jump down and then to go back `''`. Is there a way to do a shortcut such that:

`NUM <j|k>` --> `m' NUM <j|k>`

A more concrete example:

- `17j` --> `m'17j`
- `7k` --> `m'7k`

Or a way to modify the vim jumplist so it includes any multi-line j|k entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should do...

```
nnoremap j :<c-u>exe "norm! m'" . v:count1 . "j"<cr>
nnoremap k :<c-u>exe "norm! m'" . v:count1 . "k"<cr>
```

Breaking it down...

1. [`<c-u>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-U) : This clears out the line range that will be added when you start a command with a number.
2. `exe` : We are using a variable in the command so we have to stringify and pass through [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#:exe). We also need to use `:norm` for similar reasons.
3. `"norm! m'"` : The first static part of the string we submit to `:exe`: [`:norm`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:norm) plus mark setting. The `!` after `:norm` ensures we don't use remapped commands.
4. [`v:count1`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v:count1) : This special variable holds the number you entered to start the command or "1" if you didn't include one.
5. `"j"` or `"k"` : The last static part for `:exe`; the up/down command.
6. `<cr>` : Submit the whole thing for processing.

Also, the two `.` are string concatenation operators.

**Update:** I should note, since the question suggests it's what OP wants, that you can map the above to the original keys `j` and `k`. In fact, I updated the mappings to do exactly that.

Use them just like you'd have used the unmapped versions, e.g. `17j`, `7k`, `j`, etc. If you use either on the RHS of a mapping, though, you'll probably want, in most cases, to use the `noremap` type of `map` commands so you get the native behavior.